# How to track application usage in weekly,monthly and yearly in android

Tags: android

I am working on android application. I want to track application usage but i don't know how to implement it.

[image: i need to usage in minutes as shown in this image]

Comment: Google or Firebase Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to integrate firebase Analytics to your app chech [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/?gclid=CKWruamn-dICFUgW0wodWD8KeQ) for more informatoin of what it provides and how to implement it